# how to update the UILabel value by clicking UIButton IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

Hi in my Application I'm displaying the data form my local database `sqlite` in `UITableView` . In that data's I have integer value displaying in my `UILabel`. Now to want to `increment` and `decrement` the value by clicking button I have tried but its not working properly its only working one time when click the next row again its showing the old value please tell me how to resolve this one. I have created two `UIButtons` dynamically for increment and decrement.

My database data fetch code.

```
   qtt=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [self openDB];
 NSString *sql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM br"];
 sqlite3_stmt *statement;
 if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
     while (sqlite3_step(statement)== SQLITE_ROW) {

        char *field5 = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
        NSString *field5Str =[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field5];

         str2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",field5Str];

        [qtt addObject:str2];
      }

   }
```

My `UITableView` display code.

```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";

       displayCell *cell =(displayCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
      if (cell == nil) {

         cell = [[displayCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
       }

       cell.ttt.text= [self.qtt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
       button.frame = CGRectMake(130,25, 40.0, 40.0);
       [button setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       button.tag=indexPath.row;
       [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

       button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
       button1.frame = CGRectMake(200,25, 40.0, 40.0);
       [button1 setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod1:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       button1.tag=indexPath.row;
       [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];
     if([valueString isEqualToString:[self.qtt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
      {
         int value=[valueString  integerValue];
     if (self.check==YES)
       {
          value=value+1;
          str2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];
          NSLog(@"%@",str2);       
       }
       else
        {
           if (value==1)
        {

        }
        else
         {
             value=value-1;
             str2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];
             NSLog(@"%@",str2);

           }

        }
        cell.ttt.text=str2;

      }

      return cell;
   }
```

My `UIButton` Action method code.

```
  -(void)aMethod:(id)sender
 {
   self.check=YES;
   int tag=[sender tag];
   valueString=[self.qtt objectAtIndex:tag];
   [self.mytableview reloadData];
  }
 -(void)aMethod1:(id)sender
 {
    self.check=NO;
    int tag=[sender tag];
    valueString=[self.qtt objectAtIndex:tag];
    [self.mytableview reloadData]: 
 }
```

Comment: Firstly remove button alloc and init from cellForRowAtIndexPath: method as it's a bad practice. Reason that method is called depending on number of cell's. Alloc and init button in viewDidLoad method. Also use break point to check for flow of your code then you would know where it is gng after your 2nd tap.

Comment: @walle84 please tell me resolve this issue

Comment: Just move your alloc of button's from cellforrowatindex method to videDidLoad and den give a run. As every time you calling that method so it's creating new button's and adding them to table content view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you keep creating buttons every time that you go through the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code. When you call `reloadData` the first time, enough cells are available for reuse, so your code adds new buttons on top of the old ones; this happens every time you click `[+]` or `[-]`.

In order to resolve this issue, make creation of the buttons conditional. Give your buttons different tags - say, 100 for `[+]` and 101 for `[-]`. This would let you find a subview by tag, and avoid creating new buttons when they are already there. Since you need that tag in your `aMethod:` and `aMethod1:`, put the tag of `indexPath.row` on the cell itself, and use `int tag = [sender.superview tag]` expression to retrieve it.

Here is a skeleton of how you can implement this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";

    displayCell *cell =(displayCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[displayCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.ttt.text= [self.qtt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([cell.contentView viewWithTag:100] == nil) {
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(130,25, 40.0, 40.0);
        [button setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag=100;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    }
    if ([cell.contentView viewWithTag:101] == nil) {
        button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button1.frame = CGRectMake(200,25, 40.0, 40.0);
        [button1 setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod1:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button1.tag=101;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];
    }
    cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.row;
    // Remove the increment/decrement code, it does not belong here
}
```

Your event handler methods would look like this:

```
-(void)aMethod:(id)sender {
    int tag=[[sender superview] tag];
    int value=[[self.qtt objectAtIndex:tag] integerValue]+1;
    [self.qtt replaceObjectAtIndex:tag withObject:[@(value) stringValue]];
    [self.mytableview reloadData];
}

-(void)aMethod1:(id)sender {
    int tag=[[sender superview] tag];
    int value=[[self.qtt objectAtIndex:tag] integerValue]-1;
    if (value <= 0) value = 1;
    [self.qtt replaceObjectAtIndex:tag withObject:[@(value) stringValue]];
    [self.mytableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: since im new to ios developement im not getting ur point please tell where i need to change

Comment: i have tried ur code but in aMethod its showing error like superview is not found object id

Comment: @user3614966 Try again with the square brackets syntax.

Comment: @dasblinkenight its not working after change to ur code

Comment: @user3614966 See if this changes anything. You should remove the increment/decrement code from the view, it should be done in the action, not in the view on reload.